# Why does nullable cursor.getString() assignment to non-nullable String compile?

Tags: string, kotlin, android-sqlite, nullable

I have this code:

```
data class Site(val apikey: String, val id: Int) {
    companion object {
        val INVALID = Site("", 0)
    }

    lateinit var name: String
    lateinit var city: String
    lateinit var country: String
}
```

then, later in my code, I assign `site.city` with a value from an SQLite database:

```
site.city = cursor.getString(3)
```

I would assume this doesn't compile, because `cursor.getString` returns a nullable `String`, and Kotlin's strings are not nullable by default. However, this compiles fine, but crashes on runtime with:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: cursor.getString(3) must not be null

because `cursor.getString(3)` returns `null` (which is valid, the data is not in the database). I checked in the debugger, and the `getString()` call works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Java method is not annotated with either `@Nullable` or `@NonNull`, Kotlin will treat it as a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), and let you assign it to either nullable or non-nullable variables, at your own discretion. It's up to you to use the correct types.

In the specific case of a `Cursor`'s `getString` method, it's not annotated either way, and nor should it be - [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) says that implementations of the `Cursor` interface may choose whether they throw exceptions or return `null` in error cases:

> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks. Would have been nice to have some kind of warning though, when I am assigning a platform type to a non-nullable `String`. Especially if you (as Kotlin does) claim to minimise problems with `null` objects.

Comment: Initially, platform types were all treated as nullable, but that made it ridiculously hard to interact with any Java API. Hence the decision to move to the current approach, which is less safe if you're interoping with Java code, but you gain much nicer code in return. It's a tradeoff. With the current solution, modern Java APIs which are being actively maintained can add nullability annotations to be safely usable from Kotlin (and from Java as well, really).

Comment: If you want "some kind of warning", then when calling java code that is not annotated with `@Nullable` or `@NonNull` make your kotlin property - `city` - nullable, this way you will have some help from the compiler. This is not very nice approach though, because adjusting your types to help with nulls coming from java is not good. But it's the only way you have as of now.